# Support for Universal Links / App Links in custom Mobile SDK Hybrid app

Tags: mobile, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, sfdcmobilesdk-android

For a custom mobile app developed using the Mobile SDK which uses a Community Site with a custom Domain, can we support Universal Links (iOS) / App Links (Android)?

- Assume for example a Community with a custom Domain located at abcxyz.com
- In order to support Universal Links, we would need to be able to control the contents of 2 endpoints: https://abcxyz.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association and https://abcxyz.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json

By default, these endpoints are enabled with default Salesforce contents. Can they be modified? If not, is there another way to support Universal Links / App Links for apps built with the Mobile SDK?

Comment: We did this, but our .well-known is on our website which is not hosted on Salesforce. We then have "placeholder" redirection when our universal link URL path is touched to take the user to an appropriate destination.

Comment: Interesting! Are you using the [Sites URL redirects](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.sites_redirects.htm&type=5), or something else? I was under the impression that those .well-known contents cannot be "[served through a 3xx redirect](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1916/_index.html)".

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear; our universal links are to our website that then caters for the URL path and any redirection (when not accessed through the app).

Comment: Hi @JulienOuellet, were you able to overwrite the content at following locations in Salesforce for you community/site?
https://abcxyz.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association and https://abcxyz.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json

Comment: Sadly no @AbhijeetBhandari!